# "interrupted by signal 5: SIGTRAP" Android emulator - macos

Tags: android, macos, emulation

Trouble with emulator on my Mac.I got the message say :

> "*Emulator: Process finished with exit code 133 (interrupted by signal
>   5: SIGTRAP)"*

I tried almost everything, reinstall android studio ...

Any suggest.

Answer (score 0):

maybe in some functions, there are some if-else branch statements in your function. You forgot the return statement in some of your branches.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30735602)